# Optimal disk configuration for Ubuntu home file server

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, storage

I'm setting up a small Ubuntu file server at home using these 4 hard drives:

- WD Green 2TB (SATA3, 5400 RPM, 64MB cache)
- WD Black 640GB (SATA2, 7200 RPM, 32MB cache)
- 2x WD Blue 1TB (SATA3, 7200 RPM, 32MB cache)

My only specific demand is that my SQL database (few 100 GB) needs to be in a (software) RAID 1 array. The rest of the storage is just for streaming movies/music from (total about 1.5TB). Would it make sense to also include the OS and/or swap on a RAID?

How can I best configure and partition these disk, taking into account the above? Thanks!

Comment: how much data you have to store??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2x WD Blue 1TB in RAID 1
because they are identical.. with sql and important data

the 2tb disk for anything else (movies, music, ...)

the best thing is buy another 2tb disk to create another raid 1 (I won't make a raid 10 because of different usage between sql and data storage).

and the 640gb for the O.S., swap and another partition for data...

with this configuration, if the 640gb disk fails, the server won't boot, but you won't lose data!

Comment: That makes sense, especially the last sentence. Thanks!

Comment: The os should live on a mirrored drive. It's a real pain having to reinstall and configure everything.

Comment: yes, it could be; especially on linux (it once took me 3 hours to install a raid controller). but it's always better than lose data! obviously, if budget is not a problem, buy all mirrored disks!